# Latest gem not installing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundle, mongomapper

We're trying to install the latest version of Plucky to go with our Mongo installation, but running bundle update doesn't update the Plucky gem to the newest version, which is 0.6.3. Our gem version stays at 0.5.2 for some reason.

We ran both `bundle update` and `bundle update plucky`.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'mongo'
gem 'mongo_mapper'
gem 'whois'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'bson'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'rpm_contrib'
```

Commands and output:

```
[root@mongo]# bundle list
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (3.2.12)
  * actionpack (3.2.12)
  * activemodel (3.2.12)
  * activerecord (3.2.12)
  * activeresource (3.2.12)
  * activesupport (3.2.12)
  * arel (3.0.2)
  * bson (1.9.0)
  * bson_ext (1.9.0)
  * builder (3.0.4)
  * bundler (1.3.1)
  * coffee-rails (3.2.2)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (1.4.0)
  * hike (1.2.3)
  * i18n (0.6.4)
  * journey (1.0.4)
  * jquery-rails (3.0.1)
  * json (1.8.0)
  * mail (2.4.4)
  * mime-types (1.23)
  * mongo (1.9.0)
  * mongo_mapper (0.12.0)
  * multi_json (1.7.7)
  * mysql2 (0.3.11)
  * newrelic_rpm (3.6.3.111)
  * plucky (0.5.2)
...


[root@mongo]# bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Installing rake (10.1.0)
Using i18n (0.6.4)
Using multi_json (1.7.7)
Using activesupport (3.2.12)
Using builder (3.0.4)
Using activemodel (3.2.12)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.4)
Using rack (1.4.5)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using hike (1.2.3)
Using tilt (1.4.1)
Using sprockets (2.2.2)
Using actionpack (3.2.12)
Using mime-types (1.23)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.14)
Using mail (2.4.4)
Using actionmailer (3.2.12)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
Using activerecord (3.2.12)
Using activeresource (3.2.12)
Using bson (1.9.0)
Using bson_ext (1.9.0)
Using bundler (1.3.1)
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
Using execjs (1.4.0)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
Using json (1.8.0)
Using rdoc (3.12.2)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Using railties (3.2.12)
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Using jquery-rails (3.0.1)
Using mongo (1.9.0)
Using plucky (0.5.2)
...
Your bundle is updated! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
[root@mongo]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install plucky first:

`gem install plucky`

Then add the following line to you Gemfile:

`gem 'plucky', '~> 0.6.3'`

Your preference on the `'~> 0.6.3'` part.  You could go with `gem 'plucky', '0.6.3'`.

Add comment if this doesn't work.

Comment: hmm, it still ins't working. we updated our gemfile as well. any other suggestions?

Comment: this is what happens: C:\Sites\x>bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
......Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "plucky":
  In Gemfile:
    mongo_mapper (>= 0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      plucky (= 0.1.1) x86-mingw32

    plucky (0.6.3)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "tilt":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (~> 3.2.3) x86-mingw32 depends on
      tilt (~> 1.3) x86-mingw32

    rails (= 3.2.12) x86-mingw32 depends on
      tilt (1.1)

Answer (score 0):

Plucky is not in your gemfile so it must be a dependency. Almost always gems specify a version for dependency. The gem asking for plucky is probably asking for 0.5.2